# Visual Studio Code Upgrading to 1.56.0... Issues with Windows Environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyqgis

Prior to the last Visual Studio Code update, I was able to set the windows environment variables.
Now with the new update I can't and I don't know what to do.

My code is quite long so to simplify it I have tried to change the windows prompt, something simple to see if I can find the solution.

```
{
    "folders": [],
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {

            "PowerShell": {
                "source": "PowerShell",
                "icon": "terminal-powershell",
            },
            "Command Prompt": {
                "source": "Command Prompt",
                "path": [
                    "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                    "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
                ],
                "args": [],
                "icon": "star",
                
            },
            "Git Bash": {
                "source": "Git Bash"
            }
        },
        "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
            "ENV_PROMPT":"(env_qgis)",
            "PROMPT": "(Entorno Qgis) $P$G"
        },
        "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"
    }
}
```

the expected result is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What effect do you want? Please use a simple example to explain the results you expect.

Comment: Thank you @Jill Cheng. I make and update in the question with expected result. It's an easy result. What I want to really change is Python environment "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {"GDAL_DATA": "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\share\\gdal",   "GDAL_DRIVER_PATH": "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin\\gdalplugins",  "GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8": "YES", "GEOTIFF_CSV": "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\share\\epsg_csv",

Comment: In previous versions this works, and now, it's not works

Comment: -Is the VS Code terminal unavailable now? The internal terminal of VS Code integrates the terminal from the system, so please check whether the system terminal is available. For VS Code terminal settings, you could refer to this document: [Integrated Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)

Comment: Reading carefully your link I found the solution. Thanks @Jill Cheng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in this link:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

And in this paragraph the solution:

Terminal profiles

The terminal's shell defaults to $SHELL on Linux and macOS and PowerShell on Windows. Terminal profiles can be used to configure either the default or secondary shells by running the Terminal: Select Default Profile command, which is also accessible via the terminal's dropdown.

VS Code will automatically present a set of common profiles for the dropdown and also detect less common ones which will only show up when selecting a default profile.

**Note: Several terminal settings won't work automatically when set in the workspace scope, you must grant them permission to run by setting the terminal.integrated.allowWorkspaceConfiguration setting to true in your user settings.**

What I do is, go to configuration, go to user configuration and i write:

"terminal.integrated.allowWorkspaceConfiguration":true

```
{
   
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true,
    "terminal.integrated.allowWorkspaceConfiguration":true
}
```

And now my code works again:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "name": "Program",
            "path": ".."
        },
        
    ],
    "settings": {
        "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["C:/Roberto/Visual_Studio_Code/GisBike/programa;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\python;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37\\Scripts"],
        "python.pythonPath": "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37\\python.exe",
        //"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Fcc\\Desktop\\vs_qs.bat",
        //"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.12\\apps\\Python37\\python.exe",
        "editor.fontSize": 18,
        "editor.wordWrap": "on",
        "editor.wordWrapColumn": 60,

        "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {

            // GDAL
            "GDAL_DATA": "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\share\\gdal",
            "GDAL_DRIVER_PATH": "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin\\gdalplugins",
            "GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8": "YES",
            // GeoTIFF
            "GEOTIFF_CSV": "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\share\\epsg_csv",
            // Qt
            "O4W_QT_BINARIES": "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/bin",
            "O4W_QT_DOC": "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/doc",
            "O4W_QT_HEADERS": "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/include",
            "O4W_QT_LIBRARIES": "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/lib",
            "O4W_QT_PLUGINS": "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/plugins",
            "O4W_QT_PREFIX": "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5",
            "O4W_QT_TRANSLATIONS": "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Qt5/translationss",
            "QT_PLUGIN_PATH": "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\qtplugins;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qt5\\plugins",
            "PROJ_LIB":"C:\\OSGeo4W64\\share\\proj",
            // QGIS
            "OSGEO4W_ROOT": "C:\\OSGeo4W64",
            "QGIS_PREFIX_PATH": "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis",
            // Cache
            "VSI_CACHE": "TRUE",
            "VSI_CACHE_SIZE": "1000000",
            "JPEGMEM":"1000000",
            // Virtual Envoirment
            "VIRTUAL_ENV": "C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\env_qgis",
            "ENV_PROMPT":"(env_qgis)",
            "PROMPT": "(Entorno Qgis) $P$G",

            // Path
            "PATH": "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\bin;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\bin;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37\\Scripts;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qt5\\bin;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WBem;C:\\Users\\Fcc\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\Scripts;C:\\Program Files\\Exiftool;C:\\Program Files\\ffmpeg\\bin",

            // Python
            "PYTHONHOME": "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37",
            "PYTHONPATH":"C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\python;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37\\Scripts"

        },
        "git.ignoreLimitWarning": true,
        "terminal.integrated.cwd": "C:\\Roberto\\Visual_Studio_Code\\GisBike\\programa",
        "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
        "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
            "C:/Roberto/Visual_Studio_Code/GisBike/programa;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\python;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python37\\Scripts"
        ]
    },
    "emmet.extensionsPath": "",
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "cmd",
}
```